# WebControl dropdown hiding/showing panel in parent web page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a web page that has a panel that I want to show when certain options in a dropdown from a webcontrol (which is a modal) is selected and hide when not selected. I can't figure out how to get the javascript for the webcontrol to show/hide the panel in the parent class.

Web Control

```
DropDownList fieldsList = new DropDownList();
```

Web Control Javascript

```
if (selectedField === "course") {
   //This is where I want to show panel
 }
```

ASPX Code

```
 Panel fieldsInfoPanel = new Panel();
 fieldsInfoPanel.ID = "fieldsInfoPanel";
 fieldsInfoPanel.Visible = false;
 fieldContainer.Controls.Add(fieldsInfoPanel);
```

Comment: do you want to share you code / html with us

Answer (score 0):

```
//Continuation...
//Try this
//First set the attribute to your class list
//E.g: panelname is an attribute to your <li> here
<ul class="dropdown">
<li panelname="course">Courses</li>
</ul>
$('.dropdown li').click(function(){

if ($(this).attr("panelname")=== "course") {
//You can first hide others

//then call show method on the panel that was hidden
   $(".coursepanel").show();
 }else{
//doNothing
}

)}
//Good luck
```

Comment: However, Using boostrap 4 will be another good idea for your post. Search for Toggleable / Dynamic Tabs. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tabs_pills.asp

Comment: How do I add attribute panelname to listitem when I'm doing it like this fieldsList.Items.Add(new ListItem("Course", "courseName"));

Comment: I have given you the above code based on your goal but if you are referring to your snippet, i will suggest you drop your code snippets and be more explicit.